# Issue while setting a counter

Tags: android

I want to set a counter within the grey shaded Textview for each BDE. Clicking on the name of the BDE how many members are working under that particular BDE, is going to visible. But I won't be able to set the counter in the grey shaded Textview. In my case BDE name Madhu is displayed 3 times.But I don't need this. 3 is going to display in the grey shaded Textview.

[image]

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class PendingViewAdapter extends 

RecyclerView.Adapter<PendingViewHolders> {

    private List<PendingBO> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private int count=0;

    public PendingViewAdapter(Context context, List<PendingBO> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PendingViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pending_approval_row, null);
        PendingViewHolders rcv = new PendingViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PendingViewHolders holder, int position) {
        final PendingBO pendingBO = itemList.get(position);
        holder.txtOne.setText("BDE Name" + " : " + pendingBO.getEmpName());
     //   holder.txtRed.setText(pendingBO.getStatus());
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShowLeadDetails(pendingBO);
            }
        });
    }


    public void ShowLeadDetails(PendingBO pendingBO){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LeadDetailsActivity.class);
        AppController.getInstance().pendingBO = pendingBO;
     //   context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        ((Activity) context).finish();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `"BDE Name"+" : " + position` ? It depends on what your goal is.....I don´t understand really what you want to get....

Comment: I have attached an image where Madhu is going to display three times. But I don't want that. "BDE Name: Madhu" is going to visible only one time and 3 will show in the Grey Box(TextView). How to do that?

Comment: Posted a solution below, did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an intermediate List, which I would search for doubles. Each time when finding a double, remove teh double and increase the counter on the original. When this routine has gone through, copy the List to the actual itemList.

Or of course do it on the itemList itself. May have efficiency advantages, I'd jsut do the intermediate List first for...easier thinking and sorting of steps.

Quick and dirty solution:

```
this.interList = itemList;
int i = 0;
while(i<this.interList.size()){
    int j = 1;
    while(j<this.interList.size()){
        if(interList.get(i).Equals(interList.get(j)){
            interList.remove(j);
            interList.get(i).counter++;
        } else j++;
    }
}
this.itemList = this.interList;
```

Turns out, you can indeed do it without any intermediate list.